# Is there a way to set IIS7 to save changes to applicationHost.Config when using GUI

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5

I have noticed when I make changes to web sites or application folders in IIS7 the changes will be put in the web.config.  Example changes are, default documents, response headers, etc.

I would like these changes saved in the applicationHost.config.  I can use appcmd to achieve this, is there a way to achieve this using the gui?

The changes should remain site specific.

Comment: Just to be clear, you still want the changes to be *site-specific*, but saved in apphost instead of the individual web configs? Or do you want the changes to apply server-wide?

Comment: Site specific.  Thanks for the clarification question.